# Converting Youtube Data API V3 video duration to hh:mm:ss format in java?

Tags: java, regex, youtube-data-api

I am using Youtube data api v3 to get video information like title, views count and duration.The duration value is new to me as it's an `ISO8601 date` which I need to convert to a readable format like hh:mm:ss. Duration can have the following different values:

1. PT1S --> 00:01
2. PT1M --> 01:00
3. PT1H --> 01:00:00
4. PT1M1S --> 01:01
5. PT1H1S --> 01:00:01
6. PT1H1M1S --> 01:01:01

I could use [Joda Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to parse the value and calculate the duration in seconds but the library is of 500kb in size which will increase the size of my application that I don't want.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41342044/2579281

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look at this code :

```
private static HashMap<String, String> regexMap = new HashMap<>();
private static String regex2two = "(?<=[^\\d])(\\d)(?=[^\\d])";
private static String two = "0$1";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)S", "00:$1");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)M", "$1:00");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)H", "$1:00:00");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)M(\\d\\d)S", "$1:$2");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)H(\\d\\d)S", "$1:00:$2");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)H(\\d\\d)M", "$1:$2:00");
    regexMap.put("PT(\\d\\d)H(\\d\\d)M(\\d\\d)S", "$1:$2:$3");

    String[] dates = { "PT1S", "PT1M", "PT1H", "PT1M1S", "PT1H1S", "PT1H1M", "PT1H1M1S", "PT10H1M13S", "PT10H1S", "PT1M11S" };

    for (String date : dates) {
        String d = date.replaceAll(regex2two, two);
        String regex = getRegex(d);
        if (regex == null) {
            System.out.println(d + ": invalid");
            continue;
        }
        String newDate = d.replaceAll(regex, regexMap.get(regex));
        System.out.println(date + " : " +newDate);
    }    
}

private static String getRegex(String date) {
    for (String r : regexMap.keySet())
        if (Pattern.matches(r, date))
            return r;
    return null;
}
```

The `regex2two` has been used to add a leading zero`0` to 1-digit numbers. you can try this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tU6hM7).

In the `regexMap` I'v stored all 7 cases and appropriate regex-replace.

Comment: this is the best solution , till now :)

Answer (score 4):

I did by myself

Let's try

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.

public class YouTubeDurationUtils {
    /**
     * 
     * @param duration
     * @return "01:02:30"
     */
    public static String convertYouTubeDuration(String duration) {
        String youtubeDuration = duration; //"PT1H2M30S"; // "PT1M13S";
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'PT'mm'M'ss'S'");
            Date d = df.parse(youtubeDuration);
            c.setTime(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            try {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'PT'hh'H'mm'M'ss'S'");
                Date d = df.parse(youtubeDuration);
                c.setTime(d);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                try {
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("'PT'ss'S'");
                    Date d = df.parse(youtubeDuration);
                    c.setTime(d);
                } catch (ParseException e2) {
                }
            }
        }
        c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        String time = "";
        if ( c.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 0 ) {
            if ( String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR)).length() == 1 ) {
                time += "0" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            }
            else {
                time += c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            }
            time += ":";
        }
        // test minute
        if ( String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)).length() == 1 ) {
            time += "0" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }
        else {
            time += c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }
        time += ":";
        // test second
        if ( String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND)).length() == 1 ) {
            time += "0" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        }
        else {
            time += c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        }
        return time ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to deal with this problem as well. I had to convert the length to milliseconds, but once you get the secs/mins/hours variables populated you can convert to any format you want:

```
// Test Value
$vidLength = 'PT1H23M45S';

$secs = '';
$mins = '';
$hours = '';
$inspecting = '';
for($i=(strlen($vidLength)-1); $i>0; $i--){
    if(is_numeric($vidLength[$i])){
        if($inspecting == 'S'){
            $secs = $vidLength[$i].$secs;
        }
        else if($inspecting == 'M'){
            $mins = $vidLength[$i].$mins;
        }
        else if($inspecting == 'H'){
            $hours = $vidLength[$i].$hours;
        }
    }
    else {
        $inspecting = $vidLength[$i];
    }
}

$lengthInMS = 1000*(($hours*60*60) + ($mins*60) + $secs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a array of all these converted duration. So I wrote the below as a workaround and also java.time.duration was not working for me, don't know why.

```
String[] D_uration = new String[10];
while(iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()){String Apiduration1=Apiduration.replace("PT","");
                            if(Apiduration.indexOf("H")>=0){
                                String Apiduration2=Apiduration1.replace("H",":");
                                if(Apiduration.indexOf("M")>=0){
                                    String Apiduration3=Apiduration2.replace("M",":");
                                    if(Apiduration.indexOf("S")>=0){
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration3.replace("S","");


                                    }
                                    else{
                                        String Apiduration4=Apiduration2.replace("M",":00");
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration4;
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    String Apiduration4=Apiduration2.replace(":",":00:");
                                    if(Apiduration.indexOf("S")>=0){
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration4.replace("S","");


                                    }
                                    else{
                                        String Apiduration3=Apiduration4.replace(":00:",":00:00");
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration3;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else{

                                if(Apiduration.indexOf("M")>=0){
                                    String Apiduration2=Apiduration1.replace("M",":");
                                    if(Apiduration.indexOf("S")>=0){
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration2.replace("S","");


                                    }
                                    else{
                                        String Apiduration4=Apiduration2.replace(":",":00");
                                        D_uration[i]=Apiduration4;
                                    }

                                }
                                else{

                                    D_uration[i]=Apiduration1.replace("S","");




                                }
                            }
```

"Apiduration" is returned by the Youtube data Api in ISO8601 format.

Made some edits now i think it should work fine.